# Text moves left in UITextField when using RightView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

I am adding a button to a text field to clear it but when it's showing it shifts the text left, how can I keep it centre aligned. This happens regardless of my rightViewRect override, I'm just including it incase the solution will break that.

[image]

[image]

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 250/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 15
        
        // Add x button to clear text
        let clearButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        clearButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill"), for: .normal)
        clearButton.tintColor = .lightGray
        clearButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
        clearButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearText), for: .touchUpInside)
        rightView = clearButton
        rightViewMode = .whileEditing
    }
    
    override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.rightViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
        rect.origin.x -= 10 // move the clear button 10 points towards the left
        return rect
    }
    
    @objc func clearText() {
        text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all of your custom code for a clear button? `UITextField` already has the `clearButtonMode` property. How are you setting up the text field so the text is centered? That's not how a normal `UITextField` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add equal left padding

```
   let spacing: CGFloat = YourPadding
   let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: spacing, height: self.frame.height))

    leftView = paddingView
    leftViewMode = .whileEditing
```